# How to insert a Number value which is a difference between field 1 and field 2 of another table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name ITEM that consist of

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+
| Item  | PrevValue | CurrentValue |
+-------+-----------+--------------+
| ItemA |         2 |        10    |
| ItemB |         1 |      2       |
+-------+-----------+--------------+
```

And another table name PAYMENT that will require insert.

```
    INSERT INTO PAYMENT(ID, Billing_Date, Due_Date, Value_Amount)
    VALUES (1,TO_DATE('23-JULY-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('21-AUGUST-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),
**CurValue - PrevValue** );
```

How do i correctly calculate the differences between PrevValue and CurValue in ITEM and insert them into PAYMENT?

Comment: You've missed `ItemID` field in payment table, so how do you want to select a single item for payment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will be, simply INSERT....SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT(ID, Billing_Date, Due_Date, Value_Amount)
    select 1,TO_DATE('23-JULY-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('21-AUGUST-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'), (CurValue - PrevValue) from ITEM where Item = '<Item_Name>';
```

Comment: You've missed `SELECT` and this exact query will fail because it returns not scalar value

Comment: @astentx I have not missed the SELECT but the WHERE. Just added where clause which need to be there for exact one row record to be fetched.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's ok. You have `SELECT` in the very beginning, I've mislooked it.

Comment: By the way, `TO_DATE('23-JULY-2020','DD-MON-YYYY')` can be written more concisely as `date '2020-07-23'`, which will also be language-independent.